# Cannot remove from a list

Tags: grails

I am trying to remove an object from a has many relationship.
User has an object called guest, guest has a has many called children see bellow:

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    String email
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    Guest guest
}
```

Guest:

```
class Guest {

    static hasMany = [children:Child]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I use the following to add children:

```
User.guest.addToChildren(Child.get(params.id))
```

this works perfectly well. I cannot however do the following:

```
User.guest.removeFromChildren(Child.get(params.id))
```

I have also tried

```
Guest guest = User.guest
guest.removeFromChildren(Child.get(params.id))
guest.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

With no success. I have also done appropriate checks to make sure that the child instance is contained in guest and it matches

```
Child.get(params.id)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mystery part of your question is where are you getting User from?  It could be that it is a detached instance which could be causing your issues.  I would try the following:

```
Guest guest = User.guest.merge()  // make sure Guest has a hibernate context
Child child = Child.get(params)
guest.removeFromChildren(child)
// don't believe what the docs tell you
// I always have to delete the instance I am removing
// from the collection
child.delete()
```

And do this in a service method or surround it with a transaction closure.